# Как проверить что вводит пользователь по маске?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Как проверить что вводит пользователь по маске? То есть юзер вводит текст и сценарий проверяет, что он ввел, если похоже то пропускает если не похоже, то нет.

Маска примерно такая(квадратное уравнение):

```
x ** 2 − 8x + 12 = 0
5x ** 2 + 3x + 7 = 0
x ** 2 − 6x + 9 = 0
```

Comment: В каком смысле найти уравнение? Вы его нашли и написали. Что вам ещё нужно? Может найти корни уравнения?

Comment: Есть текст, в нем такого рода уравнения, мне нужна их достать через регулярные выражения.

Comment: Если вам нужно найти корни уравнения, то соизвольте показать ваши попытки и что и где у вас не получается. Иначе -> прошу идти в учебники по алгоритмам, питону и математики

Comment: Непонятно что является уравнением, а что нет. Приведите входных данных, а также данные которые проходят и не проходят валидацию. И ваши попытки решить данную проблему.

Comment: вы хотите в уравнении ax**2 + b*x +c=0 a, b и с?

Comment: Задача такая: юзер вводит уравнение и сценарий должен проверить ввел он уравнение либо что-то другое т.е как по маске, я решил что через регулярные выражение это можно реализовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По комментариям я понял, что вам нужно

Оговорюсь, что вам следовало бы понятнее объяснить задачу и в будущем, пожалуйста, подробно описывайте где и как вам нужно помочь

```
import re
EQUALITY = re.compile(r'-?[\d]*x\*\*[\d]+(\+|-)[\d]*x(\+|-)[\d]+=0')
# Данный RE не учитывает, что в уравнении не может быть элемента с любой степенью, а также не учитывает пробелы
text = ...  # весь текст
text = text.replace(' ', '')
match = EQUALITY.search(text)  # Ваше уравнение
```

При необходимости используйте *findall* для того, чтобы найти все уравнения:

```
list(EQUALITY.finditer(text))
```

[Документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: Для теста в text ввел x**2−6x+9=0 и в конце дописал print (match) возвращает None.

Comment: @AlexFirsov, ваше тире(−) не то, какое у меня (-)

Comment: Изменил тире text = "x**2-6x+9=0" -> match = EQUALITY.findall(text) -> print (match) получаю: [('-', '+')]

Comment: @AlexFirsov, прошу прощения. там должен быть finditer. сейчас поправлю ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
([x\d]+[\s*+-]+)+[\s=]+[x\d]+
```

Можно еще короче без групп:

```
[x\d]+[*-+\\\sx\d]+=[x\d]+
```

Comment: Ваш RE работает неверно. Пример: 5x5x ** 5x + 12x0x =0

Comment: Не поленился и проверил, для Вашего примера регулярка валидна

Comment: Данный пример НЕ должен матчиться. Но он матчится. https://regex101.com/r/UzfPr3/1

Comment: Если без групп то можно короче [x\d]+[*-+\\\sx\d]+=[x\d]

Comment: без групп можно мой паттерн, но в месте, где (\+|-) нужно написать [-+]{1}

Comment: Я предложил альтернативный вариант а автор сам выберет какой ему по душе. Кстати Ваш вариант менее универсален ;)

Comment: Соглашусь. Ваш вариант более универсален.